# How to add Section wise timer to Google Forms for a School Quiz?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-forms

We made an English Language Test using Google Forms which is split into 3 sections.

We would like to be able to set a time on each section (e.g. Section A = 10 min, Section B = 10 min,  Section C = 40 min).

Also, We would like the student to be able to see the countdown on each section they're doing, Is this at all possible in google-forms?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nothing like that available at the present time in Google Forms.  You might like to wait a couple of weeks since something about scripting forms is going to be announced in the google yearly conference, Google I/O.  See here: https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions/327782631

Update: Still nothing available within script wrt this question even after all this time.  Please check Rubén answer which gives reasons (and some options).

Comment: The link is broken (now redirects to the Google I/O landing page), by the other hand now the Google Apps Script Forms Service is available.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Timify.me add-ons. It's easy to use and looks good as well. 
Pros: 
  - timmer shows on the top of the page 
  - triggers the form to close upon timeout 
Cons: 
 - only paid version allows you to set logo, text, design and webcam tracking 
 - You can't customize the time countdown section-wise, countdown as a whole submission 
 
note: you need to configure timify.me with a token from timify.me web app

Comment: You can also use [AutoProctor](https://www.autoproctor.co/) It has the same pros and cons as Timify.me but is much simpler to use, and has a simpler pricing structure (after the free trial). Disclosure: I am part of the AutoProctor team.

Answer (score 0):

The Google Forms editor doesn't allow to add custom JavaScript, so it's not possible to add a timer directly to the form.

One alternative is to disable form responses submissions programmatically by using the Google Apps Script's [Forms Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms), specifically by stop accepting responses through the [setAcceptingResponses(enabled)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#setacceptingresponsesenabled) method.

A word of caution regarding the use of [time-driven triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers): The time that a script rans could be slightly randomized.

By the way Google Forms now have special features for creating quizzes, see [Create & grade quizzes with Google Forms](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7032287?hl=en). Hopefully a set timer feature will be available soon.

Answer (score -3):

I was searching for a similar answer.

Weej jamal- One way is to use Qualtrics. It has a "timing" question which can automatically submit the page once the time is complete.

So, if your sections can be placed in 3 different pages, its quite easy: Place a timing question on the top of each section with the time settings.

Comment: what is timing question? can you explain more?

Comment: The Timing question is a hidden question that can be added on any page of your survey to manage how long a participant spends on that page.
You can check for its description here - http://www.qualtrics.com/university/researchsuite/basic-building/editing-questions/question-types-guide/timing/

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.