# Google Forms Timer

Tags: forms, timer, google-forms

I am looking to create a timer on a quiz that I am creating in Google Forms.  I have found this post here - [How to add a timer to Google Forms for a School Quiz?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16394435/how-to-add-a-timer-to-google-forms-for-a-school-quiz) - from 2013 where it's mentioned that scripting might make this possible eventually.  I am wondering if anyone has figured this out or has a solution.  Ideally I would like to have the timer start when someone opens the form and auto submit or stop receiving submissions after a set elapsed time.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I believe it is not possible since there is only "Form Submit" event see <a href="https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events">here<a>, and Open event occurs only when you open it for editing, not submission. So you can't run any code during someone answering form.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a timer to Google Forms for a School Quiz?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16394435/how-to-add-a-timer-to-google-forms-for-a-school-quiz)

Answer (score 2):

A [Previous Question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/70590/how-can-i-create-a-timer-in-a-survey-in-google-forms) has mentioned this before. Right now you are correct, you cannot time a quiz using a script at the moment. Though this question does mention some "workarounds" such as using the Form Limiter tool posted in that question.

Also [this was mentioned as a viable solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16394435/how-to-add-a-timer-to-google-forms-for-a-school-quiz):

> One way is to use Qualtrics. It has a "timing" question which can
>   automatically submit the page once the time is complete.
>
> So, if your sections can be placed in 3 different pages, its quite
>   easy: Place a timing question on the top of each section with the time
>   settings.

And [This link](http://www.labnol.org/internet/schedule-google-forms/20707/) Tells you how to set the general settings of time limits (such as, open test on April 14th close on April 15th). You can set specific date limits but still no timer.

For [Further Reference](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/zWqx7yCs4Yg) View this Google Product Forum.

Answer (score 0):

Use an addon. Some work well, others don’t. A good one is [Quilgo Time and Proctoring](https://workspace.google.com/u/0/marketplace/app/quilgo_timer_proctoring/992310177365?hl=en&pann=forms_addon_widget). But as with any addon, you have to sign in. If you decide to use a different addon, be wary of the requirements. You will also have to make a Quilgo account if you use the suggested addon. But to have it stop accepting responses, you can either use an addon ([Form Limit Response - Limit Form Close](https://workspace.google.com/u/0/marketplace/app/form_limit_response_limit_form_close/646012956183?hl=en&pann=forms_addon_widget)) or just do it in the form settings (manual turn off). [Where to find manual switch for turning off responses](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w45X8.jpg)